# Battery voltage

Tags: battery, charging, hardware, android-versions, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I've just bought a replacement battery for my phone, it's exactly the same 1200 mAh 3.7v however when I look at apps showing battery info they say the battery voltage is 4mv. So what does this mean? Is it safe to use?

Comment: Are you sure you typed that correctly? Neither 4 mV nor 4 MV are plausible voltages for a cellphone battery.

Comment: @DanHulme I know that, that's why I'm asking here, it's my old phone, could it be that it's not displaying properly?

Comment: @DanHulme When looking at my old battery it displays 3mV maybe 3mV stands for somewhere in the 3v range and 4mV in 4v range, but then as my phone is only rated for 3.7v and the new battery is obviously stronger is it safe to use?

Comment: Either the thing you are reading is not the battery voltage, or the author of that app has no idea what they're doing.

Comment: @DanHulme it's the same reading with every single app next to the heading voltage: